# Pasar input text a consulta query

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, postgresql, express

```
<div id="searching">
        <input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" Nombre">
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="buscar()">
</div>
```

La idea es pasar el input a una consulta query:

```
function buscar () {
    let nombre = document.getElementById("user").value;
    console.log(nombre);
    window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
}

const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = $1', [nombre]);
    res.status(200).json(response.rows);
};
```

No sé de qué manera pasar el valor del input a la variable del query. A la variable del principio ("nicolas") la puse para testear el query y me lo devuelve perfectamente, pero no se cómo cambiarla en función del imput...

Comment: Que tipo de método estas utilizando para enviar los datos, GET o POST?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Este: router.get('/users', getUsers);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres hacer, vas a necesitar ajax y the recomiendo usar axios. De esta forma no solo lograras lo que quieres sino que tu buscador sera en tiempo real.

```html
<div id="searching">
        <input type="text" id="user" placeholder=" Nombre">
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" id="buscar">
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('user');
var buscar = document.getElementById('buscar');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
function search (query, cb) {
  axios.get('/users?q=' + query).then(function (res) {
    // pasamos los datos recibidos a un callback
    cb(res);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    // mostramos los errores en la consola en caso de que los haya
    console.log(e);
  });
}
buscar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  window.location.assign('/users?q=' + input.value);
});
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // obtenemos el texto del input al momento de ir escribiendo
  var query = e.target.value;
  search(query, function (res) {
    // mostramos los datos
    var output = [];
    var data = res.data;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      output.push('<div><strong>' + d.id + ': ' + d.nombre + '</strong></div>');
    });
    results.innerHTML = output.join('');
  });
});
</script>
```

Y desde el lado del servidor osea desde node, seria así:

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = $1', [req.query.q]);
    res.status(200).json(response.rows);
};
router.get('/users', getUsers);
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102122/discussion-on-answer-by-rimuru-tempest-pasar-input-text-a-consulta-query).